# problems with closure in JS

Tags: javascript, function, closures, scopes

I have a problem with understanding closure when I have 3 level of scopes

`https://jsfiddle.net/Ar2zee/wLy8rkyL/1/`

How I can get access to parameter "g" in level3 function,

```js
var a = 10;

function level1(b) {
  var c = 1;

  function level2(f) {
    var d = 2;

    function level3(g) {
      return a + b + c + d + f + g;
    }
    return level3()
  }
  return level2;
}
var temp = level1(10);
var temp2 = temp(10);
var temp3 = temp2(10);
console.log(temp3(10)); // or level(10)();  without variable
```

Thank you !

Comment: i gave a link to JSfiddle

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot access the parameter g"? You're not calling the `level3` function with a parameter.

Comment: See your console error

Comment: I wanna make g for example 10 and solve this problem where and how  I can get access to variable g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line:1 invokes `level1` fn and get back fn `level2` stored in alias `temp`.
Line:2 invokes `temp` fn and get back fn `level3` stored in alias `temp2`.
Line:3 now when invoking `temp2` fn you execute fn `level3` getting back the result of addition operation.

So `temp3` is not a function but a value.

```js
var a = 10;

function level1(b) {
  var c = 1;

  function level2(f) {
    var d = 2;

    function level3(g) {
      return a + b + c + d + f + g;
    }
    return level3;
  }
  return level2;
}
var temp = level1(10);
var temp2 = temp(10);
var temp3 = temp2(10);
console.log(temp3); // or level(10)();  without variable
```

Comment: Thank you so much . inside functions never use returns with parentheses just name of the functions and thats it or I can use parentheses in some cases ?

Comment: It really depends what you want to achieve, if you want a function then do not call it and if you want result, then call it (with parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
Return level3()
```

With

```
Return level3
```

Comment: what a reason to passed number inside a function if I wanna make it dynamically and change it in future for example ???